# ValueError: could not convert string to float: while loading csv and converting its items into floats

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning

I am reading data from csv file and then converting it into list. Then, I am tring to convert each value of list into float, for further processing. The code for this is:

```
def loadCsv(filename):
    lines=csv.reader(open(filename, "r"))
    dataset = list(lines)
    for i in range(len(dataset)) :
        dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
    return dataset
```

But, I get the error in:

```
dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Can someone please help me?

Comment: If the csv file contains a header then try to ignore the header.

Comment: `dataset = list(lines)[1:]` will ignore the header

Comment: Just to note that while it won't fix your issue, you could just do: `dataset = [[float(col) for col in row] for row in lines]`... then you're building a list from the source data instead of preloading it and then going through and amending it after. You might want to put a `next(lines, None)` after lines to discard the first row and see if that helps...